# How to fix deploy angular 8 project with Github pages

Tags: angular8, angular-cli-ghpages

I deployed with angular-cli-ghpages, followed the steps:https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli-ghpages

1.git remote add origin https://github.com/username/epositoryname.git

2.ng add angular-cli-ghpages

3.ng deploy

When excute deploy show me this:

ng deploy --base-href=https://github.com/Azaria-CR/portafolio1.git
 Building "dogapi". Configuration: "production". Your base-href: "https://github.com/Azaria-CR/portafolio1.git"

chunk {0} runtime-es2015.85f895af57b038f1e5b4.js (runtime) 2.82 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main-es2015.12ae7f54f3b8c7ac770e.js (main) 367 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills-es2015.0fe6949bc5ff4b784062.js (polyfills) 64 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} polyfills-es5-es2015.a83ac866abc867bfd530.js (polyfills-es5) 222 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} styles.09e2c710755c8867a460.css (styles) 0 bytes [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2019-09-18T01:53:17.038Z - Hash: 555aa990c3829b3b1bf6 - Time: 122860ms
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
ES5 bundle generation complete.
 Successfully published via angular-cli-ghpages! Have a nice day!

but it does not work

when i finish show me
the blank page

git version 2.23.0.windows.1 
Angular CLI: 8.3.4
Node: 10.16.3
npm 6.11.3

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and this worked for me:

When deploying:

```
ng deploy --base-ref=/YourRepositoryName/
```

Substitute YourRepositoryName with the name of your project and be careful with the final /.
I hope it help you to solve the problem.